# Why is systemd stopping service immediately after it is started?

Tags: linux, systemd

I created a systemd service which should invoke a shell script, when started or on reboot.

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Starts the DCCA index software

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/insiteone/bin/indexControl start
ExecStop=/opt/insiteone/bin/indexControl stop

# Execute pre and post scripts as root
#PermissionsStartOnly=true
Restart=on-abort
TimeoutSec=600
```

Initially it kept on restarting in infinite loop as soon as it is started, but when I added the `TimeoutSec` option, it called the `ExecStop` as soon as the service was started for the first time (started, and then stopped again immediately).

Any clue, where I am going wrong?

**P.S.**: `indexControl` is a shell script, which starts other processes

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You didn't tell systemd what kind of daemon this is and what to expect from it (most importantly, it needs to how to know when the daemon has finally *started*).

The default is `Type=simple`, which means the *first* process is considered the main service process. The moment it starts, the entire service is considered "active (started)"; the moment it exits, the entire service gets stopped.

The other common mode is `Type=forking`, where the initial process is expected to fork at least once and exit, leaving a child running "in background" or "daemonized" as some call it.

But if you're going through a "whateverctl" tool, you're *always* going to see the behavior that needs **`Type=forking`**, since the tool itself will try to start the daemon "in background" and exit itself.

Comment: Thanks, that works great. So if i understood correctly since the shell script "forks" starts other daemon, so you recommended `type=forking`. I have a question, if u can please help: Once i do `service index start` it shows `loaded active`, after that if i manually invoke the script to stop the services, instead of systemd, it shows `inactive dead`, but is there a way for `systemd` to show status `loaded active` if manually started as well using the script? I understand, the reason could be `systemd` does not know, if the script is accessed, so could be the reason. But any way out?

Comment: No, there isn't. If you want systemd to monitor your services, start them via systemd.

Answer (score 18):

None of the above and similar SO answers worked for me. But [this post](https://gist.github.com/drmalex07/d006f12914b21198ee43) eventually did.

```
[Unit]
Description=Setup foo
#After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/opt/foo/setup-foo.sh
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/opt/foo/teardown-foo.sh
StandardOutput=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What did the trick was the **`RemainAfterExit=true`** directive. That's because my script didn't leave any trace of itself for `systemd` to look at, so next `systemd` step was always to call `ExecStop` to stop "this strange script that doesn't leave a daemon behind". Moot but true.

**UPDATE 20180316**: Ok, I totally forgot everything about `systemd` services in these few months, so I was re-doing all the work from scratch. Fortunately I vaguely remembered about this answer, passed half an hour looking for it and now I'm here again.

I'll try to add just a couple of things I've re-learned this time: `systemd` scripts must not be placed in `/etc/init`, they stay in the more hideous `/etc/systemd/system` directory, and they're called `.service`, not `.conf`!

After the script is in the correct directory, a `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` is desirable, but won't make the script name appear in `sudo service [TAB]` autocomplete list. Nevertheless, the new service can be launched with:

```
sudo service myservice start
```

And that's it, now the service is doing what has been written for. For sure the called script won't, but this is another problem.

Comment: Correct answer!

Comment: was stuck with same issue, it got resolved because of your feedback, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Keep Type=forking and give a pid file location if your start service/app is maintaining any pid.

[Unit]
Description="Run app on boot"
After=network.target syslog.target auditd.service
 
[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
Restart=on-failure
SyslogIdentifier=webappslog
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=webapps

Comment: Can you please include a source or explain what's in there?